# why does my windows always changes time? (dual os)

Tags: dual-boot, windows, restart, time

I have dual os (not sure if it should be called dual since it's not on the same hdd)
Everytime after I switched from ubuntu back to windows 7, the time always changes. Suppose the time is 8pm now but the time would be approx 4am that each time I have to udpate the time in order for it to get to the right time.

Can someone please give me a hand?

Answer (score 3):

It's not an unknown issue. The "issue" stems from the fact that Linux uses "UTC" (Grenwich Mean Time or GMT, also referred to as Zulu) whereas Windows uses your local time to set the system master time.

You can fix this from Windows or Linux based on [these instructions at webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/09/dual-boot-fix-time-differences-between.html).

From Windows, first create `WindowsTimeFixUTC.reg` and apply it by double clicking it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
     "RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001
```

And then from a Command Prompt as Administrator:

```
>sc config w32time start= disabled
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/593859)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but don't think that warranted a -1 vote. but now i know ... btw, the link is a perma link, to an archived article [see the date in the link] soit won't be going dark anytime soon but the reason you stated does make sense, is very valid so I apologize.